# Deploy Android app to Crashlytics built with React Native based on environment using fastlane

Tags: android, react-native, crashlytics, fastlane

I tried to deploy an android app built with React Native to Crashlytics with fastlane. I was able to deploy, but by default it chose the staging version. I was wondering how I can specify to deploy the dev version (app-dev-release.apk). I've done some research but haven't found a good way yet. Below is the code

```
desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Crashlytics Beta"
  lane :dev do
    gradle(task: "assembleRelease")
    crashlytics(
      api_token: "[api_token]",
      build_secret: "[build_scret]"
    )

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I can specify the apk_path in fastfile when configuring crashlytics

```
desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Crashlytics Beta"
      lane :dev do
        gradle(task: "assembleRelease")
        crashlytics(
          api_token: "[api_token]",
          build_secret: "[build_scret]",
          apk_path: "app/build/outputs/apk/app-dev-release.apk"
        )

      end
```